# Segmentation fault when converting tabs to spaces

Tags: c

I've just bought "The C programming language" by K&R, and doing my best to do the exercises therein (if you know the book, it's exercise 1.20).

The program is meant to take input from the keyboard, and convert tab characters to appropriate amount of spaces, specified by TABLENGTH.

The code is below. When I try to run it I get segmentation fault.

```
detab.c:

#include <stdio.h>
#define TABLENGTH 8
#define MAXLINE 1000

int getline(char line[], int len);

int main()
{
    char line[MAXLINE];
    int length;

    while((length = getline(line, MAXLINE)) > 0) {
        printf("%s");
    }

}

int getline(char line[], int len)
{
  int i = 0;
  int c;

  for(i = 0; i < (MAXLINE - 1) &&
   ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'); i++) {
   // if c is tab, replace with spaces
    if(c == '\t') {
        while((TABLENGTH - (i % TABLENGTH)) != 0) {
            line[i] = ' ';
            i++;
        }
        i--;
        continue;
    }
   }
   line[i] = c;
  }
  if(c == '\n') {
   line[i] = c;
   i++;
  }

  line[i] = '\0';
  return i;
}
```

Comment: On what line is the seg fault?

Comment: At line 29, line[i] = ' '; according to gdb. There is some off logic in the while loop it seems.

Comment: Look at my updated answer, I think I got it nailed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call to `printf`

```
printf("%s");
```

is a likely cause of a segfault. It will try to interpret some arbitrary data on the stack as a pointer to a 0-terminated `char` array.

A certain way to a segfault is the loop in case of a `'\t'`:

```
if(c == '\t') {
    while((TABLENGTH - (i % TABLENGTH)) != 0) {
        line[i] = ' ';
        i++;
    }
    i--;
    continue;
}
```

Since `i >= 0` and `TABLENGTH > 0`, you always have `0 <= (i % TABLENGTH) < TABLENGTH`, so whenever you encounter a tab, you enter an infinite loop adding spaces to `line` beyond the allocated space and that will sooner or later cause a segfault when it tries to write spaces outside the process memory or into a read-only part of the memory. An easy, although not very elegant fix is changing the loop to

```
if (c == '\t') {
    do {
        line[i] = ' ';
        ++i;
    }while(((TABLENGTH - (i % TABLENGTH)) % TABLENGTH) != 0);
    --i;
    continue;
}
```

a different fix could be using a separate counter or a `switch` with a fall-through.

Comment: This would be flagged by enabling warnings in the compiler flags — or likely by compiling in debug mode for the IDE, if one is being used.

Comment: It seems I outsmarted myself on this one. This worked a charm. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 6):

Classic beginner mistake 1A: `getchar()` returns `int`, since `EOF` does not fit in a `char`.

I also think you have an indexing problem since if you find a tab, you will increase `i` in the space-insertion loop, then the `for` loop will increase `i` again, leaving weirdness in the string. This might lead to buffer overflow and the crash you're seeing.

Note that the space-insertion loop doesn't check `i` against `MAXLINE`.

Comment: I tried changing the if-test to the edit above (and changing the printf to actually use the string I wanted, but I still get a segmentation fault. I don't get a segmentation fault if my input does not include tab characters though. (I also changed the char to int, silly mistake).